# Weird lag on Chrome while it has focus

Tags: google-chrome, youtube, lag

I'm experiencing a weird lag in Chrome while it has focus. This is especially noticeable on YouTube.

Whenever I watch a video on YouTube it will periodically lag quite a lot, regardless of the video resolution (just the picture, not the sound).

However, when I Alt+Tab to another program it doesn't lag at all. (Something like I still can see the video but I Alt-Tab to another minimized window like folders and some other things the video works just fine.)

When I watch it in full screen it works just fine.

The lag occurs on other websites as well, like Facebook - very stuttering.

It has only been like this recently, and Edge works fine, but I kind of like Chrome.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it.

I uninstalled Avira and everything turned back ok. I have no idea how its Avira though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.. I didn't uninstall avira completely, but the issue was gone after uninstalling these five avira extensions.

System Speedup
Phantom VPN
Software updater
Safe Shopping
Browser Safety

My guess is that the issue is caused by one of these.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove only non-antivirus features from Avira:

- Avira Phantom VPN,
- Avira Game Booster,
- Avira System Speedup,
- Avira Optimizer Host

Here is a howto: https://bghints.blogspot.com/2021/06/uninstall-avira-unwanted-programs.html